# SAS ODS Excel with UTF-8 session encoding vs. Latin1

Tags: excel, sas

Since running my SAS base programs under a new `UTF-8` encoded environment I encounter **massive** performance problems when exporting data via `ODS excel`.

Exporting more than *N* records for a given dataset usually results in a frozen SAS-session and requires me to restart my client.

Here is what I use for testing, using a standard dataset and creating a small xlsx-File (<1MB):

```
data test03;
    set sashelp.zipcode;
    if _N_ le 3000 then output;
run;    


goptions device=png;

ods results=off;

ods excel
    file    =   "/sas_p/gridshared/ch/eg_data/regel/group_hr/export/ods_export.xlsx"
    options(    flow = "tables" start_at = "A1" embedded_titles= "yes");

proc print data=test03 label noobs;
run;

ods _all_ close;
```

I gradually increase `_N_` (line 3), and get a corresponding increase in cpu time. However, past a certain point (usually in the 4 digit range for most datasets) the program just gets stuck.

For the example above:

```
_N_ = 1000 rec → 00:00:09
_N_ = 2000 rec → 00:00:18
_N_ = 3000 rec → timeout
```

There is none of that behaviour in the old `latin1` encoded environment, where exporting all 40k records of the table above was no problem whatsoever.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Raise a ticket with SAS support.

Comment: How many columns is this?  How big is the actual file it produces?

Comment: @Tom I am ashamed to say, that after repeatet inquiries with our IT they found out they set the memory size too low - which wasn't visible for me as a mere user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you forced the dataset encoding to be `wlatin1` in your session and the ods output to also be `wlatin1`?

```
data test03(encoding='wlatin1');
    set sashelp.zipcode;
    if _N_ le 3000 then output;
run;    

filename excelout "/sas_p/gridshared/ch/eg_data/regel/group_hr/export/ods_export.xlsx"
    encoding='wlatin1'
;

goptions device=png;

ods results=off;

ods excel
    file   = excelout
    options(flow = "tables" start_at = "A1" embedded_titles= "yes")
    ;

ods excel close;
```